# SQL Server on EC2: Any pointers or suggestions?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, sql

Our production app is in a datacenter, on our gear.

We are looking to set up a DR site in Amazon EC2.

For starters, we will need SQL Server, and we will do encrypted log shipping to the instance.

Any tips for running a production SQL app on EC2 ?

We use SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition.

Specific questions and concerns:

- Where do you put the DB, since the instance SQL Server is transient storage?
  -- Answer: Use EBS, per http://aws.amazon.com/running_databases/
- My understanding is that the instances can reboot once or twice a year. How does one manage this for a production sql server setup?
  -- Answer: Use EBS for the db's, save your ami instance so it is all configured for the data location on EBS
- Can someone attest to running a 100-400gb SQL Server db on aws?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to run windows server into s2 is nothing special.
you can get more info at http://aws.amazon.com/windows/
to transfer the logs you can use different strategies
as FTP, ssh etc.